# gedit - Home key, in indented text

Tags: gedit

Seems like a simple thing, but:

Is there any way to convince gedit that pressing Home key on keyboard should go to the beginning of the text on an indented line, rather than to the 0th column?

e.g.

```
    for a in b:
```

Home should put cursor before the 'f'

Comment: I think that feature isn't available in gedit by default. I think it's called "smart home". There are search results for python script plugins that enable the feature. One such is https://github.com/kemayo/gedit-smarthome from five years ago and I'm not sure whether it works for the current gedit. Other editors such as Geany and Medit have it in their preferences by default.

Comment: This one seems more recent: https://code.google.com/p/keph-gedit-plugins/source/browse/smarthome/smarthome.plugin?spec=svnc4b39ed69e19770fb137de5e481b00c49f008718&r=c4b39ed69e19770fb137de5e481b00c49f008718

Comment: I haven't used it myself and so can't say whether it works or not. If you do try either of the plugins and one works for you, please post an answer yourself to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

From vasa1's comment:

https://github.com/kemayo/gedit-smarthome has two files (a short python script, and a metadata text file) that you can copy to a plugin area in your user directory, which make this work.

Once those files are present, gedit's Edit menu → Preferences → Plugins → *Smart Home* will enable the desired behaviour.

Presumably you could copy them to a directory in `/usr/share/gedit-2/plugins/` if they needed to be available for all users.

Comment: I tried this but could not get it to work in gEdit3.
I found another source that might work: [https://github.com/gdelhumeau/gedit-smarthome](https://github.com/gdelhumeau/gedit-smarthome)